# When rendering UserControl dynamically, How do I make it use the current session?

Tags: asp.net, session, dynamic, user-controls, render

I am rendering a custom usercontrol from a HttpHandler like such:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    string workName = context.Request.QueryString["name"];
    string workForm = RenderView("~/work/" + workName + ".ascx");
    context.Response.Write(workForm);
}

public static string RenderView(string path)
{
    Page pageHolder = new Page();
    UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);
    pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);
    StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, result, false);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that the rendered page generates a new session. (I can tell by comparing the session ID for the rendered HTML with the current session ID)

**How do I make the dynamic page use the current session?**

*Note:The code is not behind a login but will be in the future. Are there any problems I should keep in mind like supplying the session and auth cookies etc?*

Comment: I had to give you a +1 as this question better answers my question about how to dynamically load a UserControl and convert it to a string than any other answer out there.  I almost wrote the question, until I came across your question with the answer.  The RenderView() function is a great example of converting UserControls to strings.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your HttpHandler implements marker interface [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx).